# Return error code instead of message in ASP.NET Identity API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I am building a ASP.NET Web API endpoint for creating managing users. This is a REST interface and I'd like to return error codes when something goes wrong. Not just the HTTP Status Codes but include my own error code in for instance a HTTP 400 BadRequest so the client would know a detailed message to display.

I know I can override the error messages in ASP.NET Identity Core, but this is not Core, so how can I return an error code instead of the string message when using UserManager to create a new user?

```
var identityResult = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password)
```

The VS template generates a `GetErrorResult` method the returns a BadRequest which returns the `ModelState` object, but that is messages. 
How could use the validation logic of the `UserManager` but return my own error codes?

What I am really trying to achieve here is to let the client have control of the message that gets displayed by having this endpoint that creates the user simply just return an error code.

Comment: check if the return value `Contains "BadRequest"` then generate your own message and return it..

Comment: @MethodMan the IdentityResult can return quite a few different errors; "invalid email", "name taken", etc. I need to find a way to replace those with error codes so the client don't have to match the exact string when determine what message to show (the client will show it's own message based on the code).

Comment: you can do the same thing by creating a List<T> or a string[] and use the `.Contains` method on that string[] arrray .. this is probably the easiest way to approach it for something quick and dirty

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm looking for a way to override the default ModelState error responses or something like that, so I don't have to do string comparison against error messages.

Comment: Override the CreateAsync and do the validations before calling base.CreateAsync() . if any validation failed like username already exist you can return different IdentityResult Status and based on this can return different error code and messages https://iamrks-dev.medium.com/extend-identityresult-to-return-other-status-than-succeeded-failure-132cd0f4c7cf